# Why doesn't this escape character actually work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io, escaping

code:

```
file.write 'objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames\n'
```

Oddly enough, the \n is actually being printed... What is wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single quoted strings in Ruby are more 'literal' than double quoted strings; variables are not evaluated, and most escape characters don't work, with the exception of `\\` and `\'` to include literal backslashes and single quotes respectively.

Double quotes are what you want:

```
file.write "objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames\n"
```

Comment: So why would I really ever want to use single quote strings? Is it just short hand to avoid escaping characters?

Comment: It can also be useful if you don't want to interpolate. For example: `'Interpolation looks like this: #{@variable}'`, which is printed literally, as opposed to `"The value of @foo is #{@foo}"`, wherein `@foo` is evaluated and inserted.

Comment: @Zombies Single quoted string require less work on Ruby's side.  They're a little faster to use when you know you're not going to need things like variable interpolation.

Answer (score 4):

The *only* two escape sequences allowed in a single quoted string are `\'` (for a single quote) and `\\` (for a single backslash). If you want to use other escape sequences, like `\n` (for newline), you have to use a double quoted string.

So, this will work:

```
file.write "objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames\n"
```

Although I personally would simply use `puts` here, which already adds a newline:

```
file.puts 'objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames'
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using single quotes. The only escape sequences allowed in single quotes are `\\` for `\` and `\'` for `'`. Use double quotes and `\n` will work as expected.

Comment: Actually, not even `\\` works. (Which BTW means that you cannot have a single quoted string that ends with an odd number of backslashes.)

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Note that `'\\'.size == 1`, which is an odd number.

Comment: Yes, of course. How stupid of me. I typed `'\\'` into IRB and got back `"\\"` and I thought: hey, I put two backslashes in and two came out, therefore they weren't escaped. But, of course, they are printed back in escaped form. Duh!